# Clean dual boot installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

I have an SSD with windows 10 (EFI). I want to install ubuntu into a second ssd to have a dual boot.

I really don't want to mixed them, that say that if i want to reset windows i just have to unplug my linux ssd, and replug it when the reset will be done. And everything have to be ok after that.
Also that say that if i unplug one of the two ssd i can boot on the only one ssd without problem.

I want to know if the default ubuntu installation give me what i want or if i have to do something with the grub or something else to perform that thing.

Thanks.

Comment: If you unplug the Windows drive you can just install Ubuntu to that drive. But UEFI forgets UEFI boot entries when a drive is unplugged, but most find Windows entries in ESP, but not necessarily the Ubuntu entries. You then have to use efibootmgr to add entry or reinstall grub. Once installed you should be able to leave both drives plugged in. Grub normally lets you boot either system if Windows fast start up is off, or you can choose to boot from UEFI boot menu  either install.

Comment: So if I install Ubuntu with the windows SSD beside it will write into the windows SSD ? Why and what ubuntu write in it ?

Comment: Ubuntu's grub installs a folder in the ESP - efi system partition. Then both grub boot loader & Windows boot loaders have separate folders in the ESP. That is with UEFI installs, not BIOS based installs. If you leave Windows drive installed you need to manually partition the Ubuntu drive with gpt and include an ESP (even if not immediately used). https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation I prefer to partition in advance with gparted, but you still have to choose (change button) using Something Else install option.

Comment: Thanks i've partitioned myself during installation, and i've create a partition for efi, swap et / and it's work, everythings is ok, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If windows is installed in uefi, you have to boot your ubuntu installation in uefi too. During installation you have to manually allocate your partitions, that is to says :

- Create a partition for efi (250MB)
- Create a partition for swap (2xRAM)
- Create an EXT4 partition (disk space remainder)

After the installation your computer will still boot first to your windows, so you will not have access to grub. To change that, change the boot order in your bios and make ubuntu uefi in first position. You should have access to grub and you will be able to choose what launch between windows and ubuntu.

Comment: Only 2GB for the swap  partition? afaik there is no such thing as a fat4 partition.

Comment: Yes, i've read that for modern computers swap is not very useful and used. And they say that 1GB or 2GB is sufficient.  But maybe i'm wrong, please could you tell me how much you will allocate and why. Thanks i edit to EXT4.

Comment: [Ubuntu Documentation Swap FAQ](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) In particular look at the Example Scenarios table. In my experience with installing Ubuntu on computers with an SSD the Ubuntu installer automatically allocates the swap partition size a little bit larger than the amount listed in the "No hibernation" column.

Comment: They says "if you use hibernation" you have to have a minimum of the size of your ram. This hibernation mode is it actived by default, is it really needed ?

Comment: If you never use hibernation it is not needed. Personally I never use hibernation, instead I make it a habit to save all of my work before shutting down the computer.